# Getting COUNT and SKIP TAKE in one operation with Linq to Entities

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a data call in a Linq to Entities powered data access layer that is designed to make paged calls.

In doing so, I need to select a subset of the data, say 50 rows, but also get the count of all matches to know how many total matches exist to be paged through.

Currently, I'm doing the following:

```
var queryResult = DatabaseContext.Table
    .Where(x => !x.IsDeleted)
    .Where(p => (
            p.PropertyOne.ToLower().Contains(query) ||
            p.PropertyTwo.ToLower().Contains(query) 
            ));

int count = queryResult.Count();

var returnData = queryResult
    .OrderBy(i => i.ID)
    .Skip(start).Take((length))
    .Select(y => new ObjectDTO
    {
        PropertyOne = y.PropertyOne,
        PropertyTwo = y.PropertyTwo
    }
    .AsEnumerable();
```

This results in two costly database operations. The `COUNT` operation for some reason actually takes longer than the `SELECT` operation.

Is there a way to get count and a subset in the same operation?

The logical flow to me says we do the following:

- Look at Table
- Find Items in Table that match a condition
- Get a Count of all matches
- Return a numbered subset of the matches

This seems possible in one operation, but I cannot figure out how.

**Attempt One, Slower**

Tried D Stanley's suggestion of casting the full result set to a `List` and doing count and memory in paging, but it is roughly 2x slower (6.9s avg vs 3.9s avg)

It's worth mentioning the data set is roughly 25,000 records, with over a dozen related tables that are searched in a JOIN.

Comment: What if you enumerate the `queryResult` to a `List<T>` and use `.Count` on the list, is it faster?

Comment: FYI the count takes longer because it has to go through all the rows in your table where as the second one can stop as soon as it get `start` + `length` matches.

Comment: @diemaus That would pull a lot more data than is needed and likely would be slower depending on the amount of data.

Comment: @juharr as you said, it depends on how much data you are retrieving. Why not try it out? :)

Comment: You can try Entity Framework Extended https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended This will allow you to to do both operations in a single call to the database. It's still not likely to be quick given the nature of the query.

Comment: You didn't use the value of `count` in the code. I mean `int count = queryResult.Count();`

Comment: @HuiZhao Happens later, wasn't relevant here

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible, but it probably won't be much faster because of the criteria you're using.  Since you're searching for text within a column value, you cannot use an index and thus must do a table scan.  You *could* do a single query to get *all* records and do the `Count` and `Skip/Take` in linq-to-objects:

```
var queryResult = DatabaseContext.Table
    .Where(x => !x.IsDeleted)
    .OrderBy(i => i.ID)
    .Where(p => (
            p.PropertyOne.ToLower().Contains(query) ||
            p.PropertyTwo.ToLower().Contains(query) 
            ))
    .ToList();

int count = queryResult.Count();  // now this will be a linq-to-objects query

var returnData = queryResult
    .Skip(start).Take((length))
    .AsEnumerable();
```

but you'd have to try it to see if it would be any faster.

Comment: But, of course this will be problem if there are not few rows in the table.

Comment: Possible, but it may still be faster that doing _two table scans_ on the database.

Comment: Once you've called `.ToList()`, you've got a list in memory. Just access the `Count` property instead of calling the `.Count()` method -- though LINQ should see the underlying property and use that anyway.

Comment: The only downside is I'm casting to a data transfer object with a SELECT statement I didn't show. That might change things. Let me update the question.

Comment: Then just add the `Select` to the base query - then you're only transferring the columns you need over the wire and it doesn't affect the `Count`.

Comment: I'll try it both ways and let you know

Comment: Unfortunately @DStanley, casting to the list and filtering in memory is actually slower on most tables.

Comment: @afrazier fun fact: `IEnumerable<T>.Count()` internally looks at .Count on  Lists (or `ICollection`s) so the performance-impact is very slight. However; it does not do this for `IEnumerable<T>.Any()` which coincidentally means that on lists, `.Count()` is actually _faster_ than `.Any()`. source: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,1194

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
db.Products
   .Take(10)
   .Select(p => new 
                {
                    Total = db.Products.Count, 
                    Product = p
                })
```

If that's no good, it may help to know that in SQL, you get the total results and one page of them using OVER().

Answer (score 0):

I have tried very hard to find an answer to this myself with no success.

I decided this is a limitation of LINQ to Entities, and made a stored procedure instead of spending more time in LINQ.

In the stored procedure, I would do something like this

```
--Get expensive query into temp table
SELECT *
INTO #t
FROM table
WHERE <expensive query here>

--Set the output param of your stored procedure
SET @totalRows = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #t);

--Select your final result set
SELECT *
FROM #t
OFFSET (0) ROWS
FETCH NEXT (50) ROWS ONLY;

--Cleanup
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #t;
```