# Create anonymous object via LINQ lambda from one result

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have the following query

```
var resources = Db.RESOURCE_Resource
                .Include(i => i.RESOURCE_Value.Where(s => s.ApplicatieID == applicationId))
                .Include(i => i.RESOURCE_Category)
                .Where(w => missingCultureIds.All(a => w.RESOURCE_Value.All(an => an.CultureID != a)));
```

Besides from wanting to return the items which are returned by the query, I also want to return the count of the list. After this query a few more filters will be implemented on the IQueryable, but I need the count beforehand.

Cant I change the query so it includes the count without it leading to multiple queries? I want the count of all these items, but I want only the data of a couple of items (implemented afterwards with

```
resources.Skip(pageSize).Take(pageSize*pageNumber)
```

So I want to generate a query that sends only the reduced list of object, but the count of more objects. I know you can make anonymous types from a collection like

`.Select(s => new { property = s.item }`

Is it possible to do what I want or do I have to handle this via a stored procedure/table valued function?

Comment: `Cant I change the query so it includes the count without it leading to multiple queries?` Not really, no. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29218164/getting-count-and-skip-take-in-one-operation-with-linq-to-entities .

Comment: Using .Include with a .Where won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either need two queries, or you need to just query for the larger data set and then filter it with code. Which way performs best will depend upon the size of the larger data set.

**One query:**

```
 var resources = Db.RESOURCE_Resource
     .Include(i => i.RESOURCE_Value.Where(s => s.ApplicatieID == applicationId))
     .Include(i => i.RESOURCE_Category)
     .Where(w => missingCultureIds.All(a => w.RESOURCE_Value.All(an => an.CultureID != a))).ToList();

var count = resources.Count();
var results = resources.Skip(pageSize).Take(pageSize*pageNumber);
```

**Two queries:**

```
var count = Db.RESOURCE_Resource
    .Include(i => i.RESOURCE_Value.Where(s => s.ApplicatieID == applicationId))
    .Include(i => i.RESOURCE_Category)
    .Where(w => missingCultureIds.All(a => w.RESOURCE_Value.All(an => an.CultureID != a))).Count();
var results = Db.RESOURCE_Resource
    .Include(i => i.RESOURCE_Value.Where(s => s.ApplicatieID == applicationId))
    .Include(i => i.RESOURCE_Category)
    .Where(w => missingCultureIds.All(a => w.RESOURCE_Value.All(an => an.CultureID != a))).Skip(pageSize).Take(pageSize*pageNumber);
```

Comment: Your two solutions are identical.  Both perform two queries, which the OP specifically said they're asking how to not do.

Comment: Yes, just spotted that. User error :)

Comment: After your edit the two solutions are no longer textually identical, but they're still semantically identical.

Comment: You're right. I meant for the first solution to execute before the count. I've added a ToList() to do this.

Comment: you don't need to project ToList before count. You can (more efficiently) count the IQueryable<T>. It issues a Sql COUNT query.

Comment: That's going to be *worse* than just executing the two queries (unless there's only one page worth of data in the unpaged result, which shouldn't be often if the query is being paginated).